# Extract only lines that do not have a period at the end

Tags: r, regex

Hello I'm having a problem.
My text file is similar to this:

```
Section 1 Blah blah blah
Random sentence.
Section 2 Blah blah blah
Random sentence.
Section 564 of the blah blah blah.
Section 578 of the blah blah blah had
the following requirements.
```

I'm trying to obtain just:

```
Section 1 Blah blah blah
Section 2 Blah blah blah
```

However, I am getting:

```
Section 1 Blah blah blah
Section 2 Blah blah blah
Section 564 of the blah blah blah.
Section 578 of the blah blah blah had
```

My code to get this is:

```
grep("(^(\\w+)\\s\\d+\\s+)",file, value=TRUE)
```

I'm trying to get any pattern of words with a number of any length, so in this case, Section with any number, followed by some spaces and the rest of the line. However, I do not want to obtain this, if the content on this line is a full sentence with a period. I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: I find it questionable to edit the question to include additional requirements after answers have been provided.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to add the period. Thanks. And, am I not supposed to do so? I'm relatively new to stack overflow, so I didn't know. Sorry.

Comment: Generally speaking it is the right thing to edit the question to include further information. However, you should not edit the question in a way that invalidates formally correct answers (see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521/editing-question-for-new-answer) for a discussion). Your case is borderline, I think I would have opted to include the multi-line case as a "bonus question", leaving the original question intact. Adding the missing period for the multi-line case was correct, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can opt to match anything except something in your regex. To break down the pattern:

- `[^]` will match anything except what is after the `^` inside the braces
- `\\.` is a literal `.`, escaped so it doesn't mean "any character"
- `$` means the end of the string.

So this matches any string that ends in something other than a period. You can add other pattern elements in front of this if you need to.

Updated to address lowercase letters beginning the strings. We can figure out which of these exist and then remove the ones with an index one smaller. Then proceed to remove those ending with full stops as before.

```r
text = c(
  "Section 1 Blah blah blah",
  "Random sentence.",
  "Section 2 Blah blah blah",
  "Random sentence.",
  "Section 564 of the blah blah blah.",
  "Section 578 of the blah blah blah had",
  "the following requirements."
)

library(stringr)

remove_sentences <- function(strings){
  lower <- str_which(strings, "^[:lower:]")
  no_next_lower <- strings[-(lower - 1)]
  str_subset(no_next_lower, "[^\\.]$")
}

text %>%
  remove_sentences %>%
  writeLines
#> Section 1 Blah blah blah
#> Section 2 Blah blah blah
```

Created on 2018-06-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I just forgot to add one part to my question. Say "Section 564 of the blah blah blah." spanned two lines. The first line had "Section 564 of the", while the next line began with "blah blah blah". Would there be a way to still exclude that sentence? Maybe like detecting a lowercase letter on the second line

Comment: You can of course detect a line that begins with a lowercase letter. I suggest you resubmit or edit the question to reflect the new criteria

Answer (score 2):

You can expand your regex to match any character until the end of the line but disallow a literal `.` in the end. Example for the original question:

```
file <- c('Section 1 Blah blah blah',
'Random sentence.',
'Section 2 Blah blah blah',
'Random sentence.',
'Section 564 of the blah blah blah.')

grep("(^(\\w+)\\s\\d+\\s+.*[^\\.]$)",file, value=TRUE)
#> [1] "Section 1 Blah blah blah" "Section 2 Blah blah blah"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just one more question, do you know how I would do this across lines. For example, say "Section 564 of the blah blah blah." spanned two lines. The first line had "Section 564 of the", while the next line began with "blah blah blah". Would there be a way to still exclude that sentence?

Comment: @J.Doe I see no way haw to distinguish the case of a multi-line section title from a single line section title (w/o dot) followed by a regular sentence (like the first two lines of your sample).

Comment: Ok. Thats fine. I was just thinking if there was a way to detect if the second line started with a lowercase letter. If so, and that were combined with the code you provided, maybe the unwanted sentence could be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

One can achieve the desired result by checking if current line doesn't contains any `.` at then end and next line starts with a `lower-case`. An option is to use `dplyr::lead` to get next line but other option is to use `tail(text,-1)` in `base-R`.

The solution will be as:

```
text <- c(  
"Section 1 Blah blah blah",
"Random sentence.",
"Section 2 Blah blah blah",
"Random sentence.",
"Section 564 of the blah blah blah.",
"Section 578 of the blah blah blah had",
"the following requirements.")

# The below code select a line that starts with caps-letter, doesn't 
# contains . and next line is not started with lower-letter.
text[grepl("^[A-Z].*[^.]$",text) & !c(tail(grepl("^[a-z].*",text),-1),FALSE)]

# [1] "Section 1 Blah blah blah"
# [2] "Section 2 Blah blah blah"
```

**Regex used:**

**A. "^[A-Z].*[^.]$"**

- `^[A-Z]` - Starts with caps character
- `.*`     - followed by any number of any characters
- `[^.]$`  - Doesn't ends with `.`

**B. "^[a-z].*"**

- `^[a-z]` - Starts with lower character
- `.*`     - followed by any number of any characters